# C: writing a bash shell, how to mimic bash shell behavior for SIGINT

Tags: c, shell, signals, stdin

When receiving a SIGINT signal, the bash shell quits the line the user is currently writing, and prints out a new prompt, but it doens't exit. How can I mimic that behavior? I'm writing my own shell and I want the shell to continue running on SIGINT. I'm not sure how to properly terminate the previous `fget` from reading from stdin and then print out a new prompt:

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_args()
{
    char *args = calloc(sizeof(char), 1024);
    fgets(args, 1023, stdin);
    char *pter = strrchr(args, '\n');
    if (pter)
        *pter = 0;
    return args;
}

void sigintHandler(int sig_num)
{
    // Reset handler to catch SIGINT next time.
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    printf("Received ctrl c\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char host_name[64]; // hostname
    gethostname(host_name, 64);
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    while (1)
    {
        if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        {
            printf("[%s]$ ", host_name);
            char *line = get_args();
            printf("\nline: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

How can I terminate fgets from running after SIGINT so that the prompt (hostname) can be printed again?

Comment: You cannot call printf from a signal handler. And you really should not.

Comment: That was a debug statement to make sure I received the SIGINT, but I'm not sure how to kill the previous fget from reading and start the loop over so the prompt will print.

Comment: Debugging statements that can cause bugs are actually bugging statements. Junst dont do it. Even if it appears to work initially. It will bite back.

Comment: There are two ways: 1) set a (global) flag 2) siglongjump. Read Stevens for the details. There might be a third way, involving a pipe-trick, Im not sure.

Comment: would using siglongjump kill off fgets because it would still be reading from stdin

Comment: Siglongjump can cause resource-leaks, if used unwisely.

Comment: i am tring to implement this using global flag, but nothing fixes the problem of the fact that fgets is waiting for stdin when SIGINT is intercepted, and im not sure how to kill it. Using a global flag doesnt change that

Comment: Maybe avoid stdio, and use plain read+select. Look into the source to see how bash does it.

Comment: I was able to do this with `setlongjmp` and `sigsetjmp`! thanks!

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer with `setlongjmp` and `sigsetjmp`**:
After some research, it seemed the easiest way (least lines of code) to cancel an existing `fgets`, `scanf`, etc call that's waiting to read from `stdin` after a `SIGINT` interrupt is to use a `siglongjmp` statement.

Using `sigsetjmp`, you can declare a jump location (in my case it is in main, so that my infinite while loop can print the prompt again. Then, inside the `SIGINT` handler, you can call `siglongjmp`.

Relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

// initialize marker for jump
sigjmp_buf mark;

// handler for SIGINT creates another SIGINT handler
// for the next SIGINT interrupt, and jumps back
// to infinite lopp
void sigintHandler(int sig_num)
{
    // Reset handler to catch SIGINT next time.
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    // jump back to main to abort current stdin from fgets
    siglongjmp(mark, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // signal handler for SIGINT
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    // set the marker to this point in main
    sigsetjmp(mark, 1);

    while (1)
    {
        if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        {
            // some code that prints the prompt in the form
            // of username@hostname:cwd$ 
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```